# Can I use CSS3 with XHTML 1.0?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Can I use CSS3 properties with XHTML, or only with HTML5 web pages?

Is there any relation between HTML version and CSS, or is it totally indifferent?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that XHTML is just HTML written to conform with XML syntax rules, so you can have XHTML5 if you like. See http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/introduction.html#html-vs-xhtml. (That doesn’t have any bearing on what CSS properties you can use though.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the browser support CSS3 and XHTML 1.0, you can use both.

The two standards are not tightly linked to each other, that is what version of CSS you use has no relation to what version of (X)HTML you use.

This is one of the benefits of the separation of content (XHTML) from display (CSS).

Comment: In fact, they're not linked at all.

Comment: @BoltClock - Well... they are both meant to be used together.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can, I just check this fragment of code:

```
<div style="text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px #000;">Something</div>
```

The style is definitely a CSS3 only. And according the http://w3c.org/validator, this bit of code is valid. If you have any doubt, just use that to check

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the properties (or selectors) and the browsers that undersands it would render it no matter what DOCTYPE you use. The CSS might not validate though.
Thank you progressive enhancement and graceful degradation!