# DOCTYPE Declaration IE Issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

On my webpage I am applying `css zoom` to `<body>` tag to fit the web page content on screen properly. My problem is when I use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
```

zoom doesn't work in IE but works in Firefox and Chrome.  When I just put

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" >
<HTML>
```

it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. Any idea what could be a cross browser compatible solution?

Comment: Exact duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117699/css-zoom-property

Comment: @trapper struggling to figure out why its exact duplicate, I have no problem working with zoom across all browsers.. it just that <!DOCTYPE> is creating problems (thats what I guess)

Comment: So if you use the complete FSI+FPI in you DOCTYPE, zoon no longer works in IE?

Answer (score 0):

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is all you need for HTML5, which is what you should be using with CSS3

Comment: so just `<!DOCTYPE html>`.. that's it ?

Comment: You can use css3 and xhtml together, Random. Re: [Can I use CSS3 with XHTML 1.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9318237/can-i-use-css3-with-xhtml-1-0)

Comment: what does the DOCTYPE has to do with CSS Properties?

Comment: @kush, you can do a lot of things, but why?

Comment: @trapper I was just saying it is technically possible. I would really like to know why browsers are ignoring css based on doctype.

Comment: You are stating that HTML5 DOCTYPE vs. XHTML4 DOCTYPE has any kind of whatsoever relationship with CSS Properties in IE? You should not try to confuse it yourself mate. The only way compatibility mode is triggered is the absence of a DOCTYPE of a wrong spelled DOCTYPE. Maybe you are confused as to eaxctly what does a DOCTYPE do?

Answer (score 0):

Zoom is supported by IE, opera and chrome but for firefox you can use

```
div.zoom {
      zoom: 2; /* all browsers */
     -moz-transform: scale(2);  /* Firefox */
}
```

CSS3 is not related to the doctype.

Comment: thats certainly not true, zoom works across all major browsers

Answer (score 0):

It appears you want to use "almost standards compliance mode" in chrome and "standards compliance mode" in Internet Explorer.

Use

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

to put IE in chrome in "almost standards compliance mode" and then

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=«whatever version of IE you're developing for, for example 8»" />
```

to force IE in standards compliance mode.